# Is the divergence between Round and setting an explicit precision intentional or a bug?

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, rounding

**Introductory remark:** I take it (from *Mathematica's* [online documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)), that `Precision` is effectively the number of significant digits, as seen by the system.

- For literals, precision is set using backquotes, e.g. `` 2.501`1 ``, which yields a `3.`. Calling `Precision` on this result gives `1`, as expected.
- On the other hand, there is `Round`, which, well, rounds according to the unbiased next-to-even-scheme, e.g.:

  $\quad \quad $`Round[{2.501, 3.501, 2.401, 3.401, 2.5, 3.5, 2.4, 3.4}]`

  gives the integers

  $\quad \quad $`{3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 4, 2, 3}`

**But:**

$\quad \quad $`` {2.501`1, 3.501`1, 2.401`1, 3.401`1, 2.5`1, 3.5`1, 2.4`1, 3.4`1} ``

yields an unexpected difference at the 5th position:

$\quad \quad $`{3., 4., 2., 3., 3., 4., 2., 3.}`

So, specifying a precision explicitly (which should be a number of significant digits, according to documentation), gives different results than rounding the same literals to the same number of significant digits.

While the explicit precision statement `` ` `` does show the number rounded, its method is not next-to-nearest-even, but the biased next-to-larger-absolute (i.e. "up-from-0.5").

**My question therefore is:**

Did I miss some of the intricacies of the assorted norms or should *Mathematica* round the same, regardless of how the number of significant digits is specified (`Round` or `` `1 (* or more, according to magnitude before the decimal separator *) ``)?

**Further findings**

`` 2.5`1*2.`1 `` results in a displayed `0` with `Precision` yielding not `1`, as expected, but `0.69897`. Checking further using

```
{#, Round[#], Accuracy[#], Precision[#]}&/@{2.5`1, 2.`1, 2.5`1+2.`1, 2.5`1*2.`1}
```

which leads to

$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
\bf input& \bf output& \bf Round&\bf Accuracy&\bf Precision\\
2.5`1& 2. & 2 & 0.60206 & 1. \\
2.`1& 2. & 2 & 0.69897 & 1. \\
2.5`1+2.`1& 4. & 4 & 0.346787 & 1. \\
2.5`1*2.`1& 0. & 5 & 0. & 0.69897 \\
\end{array}
$$

adds to my confusion about the semantics of significant digits in *Mathematica*.

Reference: [`NumericalPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html)

---

> **Extension/Background for the Question**
>
> The reason for me asking this question is, that I wanted to implement calculations with *Mathematica*, which obey the rule, that any (final) results shall be displayed with the minimum number of significant digits of all values/measurements used as input.
>
> After consulting the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html), I thought, that setting an input value's precision explicitly would have been the key to this.
>
> Now, however, I am at a loss, since
>
> 1. the rounding behavior of the frontend differs from `Round`
> 2. arithmetic operations like multiplications change the precision of the result in forseeable, but practically less usable ways.
>
> Obviously, I will have to turn to the hard way and track the number of significant digits myself and round as appropriate using `Round`.

Comment: Almost certainly `Round` is using guard digits, so the ones ending `.501\`1` will round up whereas the ones with `.5\`1` will round to even.

Comment: `Round[]` respects the rounding rules "nearest-to-even" of IEEE 754 (used quite everywhere), while the backtick (aka Precision) does not, albeit in the same application.

It looks like a bug to me, since significance is dealt with differently with respect to rounding.

Comment: By the way, if you want Daniel Lichtblau to see your comment response, you should add an @DanielLichtblau tag into your comment, otherwise he will not be alerted to your response. This trick works on any StackExchange site, and is very useful.

Comment: Thx!
On the other hand: If anyone is interested, I trust he will be coming back either way - I would rather not pester people, if it can be avoided.

Nevertheless: Again: Thank you for sharing this information! :)

Comment: @daniellichtblau (sorry - just trying out the hint of @dumpsterdoofus): ``.501`1`` rounds up because it is nearer to 1. than to 0. The question is: Why does <even>.5 round to <even> with Round, while it rounds to <even+1>. when setting precision. This _may_ be correct, according to standards, but I just fail to see how.

Comment: I don't think this is precisely right: "While the explicit precision statement `` ` `` does round..."  It's the FE that typesets ``2.5`1`` as a `3.`.  The value is still ``2.5`1.``.  One might still consider it a bug (or at least inconsistent), and typesetting is important (for printing reports, say).

Comment: It gets even weirder: Try multiplying ``2.5`1*2.1`1``, which returns `0`. Calling `Precision[]` on the result is less than 1. This does not match my idea of how significant digits are supposed to be working.

Surely, I must be missing something, but what?

Comment: the last point might deserve its own question. Id stop short of calling the rounding issue a bug unless the docs state a next to even rule is supposed to be applied.

Comment: I am not saying "bug", but the behavior actually seems to contradict other parts of the system, as well as the documentation. Maybe somebody can clear all this up.

Comment: As to ``2.5`1*2.1`1`` displaying 0 instead of a red output, also seems weird, but it is still a display problem only. It should give about 5.25 with a 40% uncertainty aprox (less precision than a significant digit)

Comment: "The question is: Why does <even>.5 round to <even> with Round, while it rounds to <even+1>. when setting precision." To respond, I'll note that I only get evens for that latter scenario. `In[1]:= Round[{2.5\`1, 3.5\`1, 4.5\`1, 5.5\`1, 12.5\`1, 13.5\`1}]

Out[1]= {2, 4, 4, 6, 12, 14}`. When one instead uses `evenorodd.501\`1` then the guard bits (which lie beyond the given precision boundary) influence the decision and rounding is upward (with `evenorodd.499`\1` it woud of course be sownward).

Comment: As to the extension, yes, you should round at the end with the min of the input precisions (or use `SetPrecision` perhaps) instead of using the automatic precision tracking of Mathematica. Because the Mathematica precision tracking does not work as you intend (but in a smarter way that makes sense in general)

Comment: `Precision` might be of some value, but there would actually be real practical value in having a means of tracking the number of significant digits at hand.

In combination with the inconsistent behavior of the frontend (when compared to `Round`), I see - in this state - no very practical use of `Precision` and `Accuracy`. :|

Then, however, tracking significant digits might be worth a feature request to Wolfram in the area covered by `Quantity`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: 
I am not sure, what `Round` applied to a precision-governed value demonstrates. As I pointed out, round-to-nearest-even (which is the standard method of unbiased rounding not only for `Round`, but quite every numerical system at hand, including programming language implementations), is implemented by `Round`, so 2.5-->2, 3.5-->4, but 2.501-->3, 3.501-->4.

Giving a specific precision before rounding with `Round` does not change anything: `Round[{2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 12.5, 13.5}]` yields exactly the same result: `{2, 4, 4, 6, 12, 14}`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [`Precision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Precision.html), the precision of a number `x` with absolute uncertainty `dx` is `p -> -Log10[dx / x]`.  Conversely the uncertainty is given by `dx -> x * 10^-p`.

For a calculation `f[x, y, ...]`, the precision is estimated by `Dt[f[x, y, ...] / f[x, y, ...]`, where `Dt[x]` represents the uncertainty of `x` and so on for any other variables.  I'll show that for the sum and product, this formula gives the precision exactly as computed by *Mathematica* for the OP's inputs:

```
inputs = {Dt[x] -> 2.5*10^-1, Dt[y] -> 2.1*10^-1, x -> 2.5`1, y -> 2.1`1}
```

Thus the behavior of precision and accuracy will be seen to be entirely consistent with the theory and the design of *Mathematica*.  I'll then explain a little about how the FE displays numbers, but I don't know enough to give a full explanation.

**Sums**

```
-Log10[Dt[x + y]/(x + y) /. inputs] // FullForm
(*  1.  *)

x + y /. inputs // FullForm
(*  4.6`1.  *)
```

**Products**

```
-Log10[Dt[x*y]/(x*y) /. inputs] // FullForm
(*  0.6989700043360187  *)

x*y /. inputs // FullForm
(*  5.25`0.6989700043360187  *)
```

**Display digits**

Note that `` 2.5`1 * 2.1`1 `` is not in fact `0`, but `` 5.25`0.69... ``.  It is just typeset as `0.`.  To display the first digit (of this number between `1` and `10`), we should have an uncertainty less than `dx = 1.` or an [`Accuracy`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Accuracy.html) of at least `-Log10[dx] == 0.`  But the uncertainty is

```
5.25*10^-0.6989700043360187` 
(*  1.05  *)
```

and the accuracy is

```
-Log10[1.05]
5.25`0.6989700043360187 // Accuracy
(*
  -0.0211893
  -0.0211893
*)
```

To get one digit we need at least a precision `p` given by the following:

```
NSolve[5.25*10^-p == 1]
(*  {{p -> 0.720159}}  *)
```

This is the borderline value.  In this particular case, a slightly higher precision (`p + 4.47741*10^-15`) is needed to get the FE to display the first digit `5`.  I don't know why.

I also do not know what the FE is supposed to do when it rounds. On a logarithmic scale, `2.5` is closer to `3.` than `2.`, but I've never seen an argument for (or against) rounding on that basis.  [Rounding away from zero](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_away_from_zero) (Wikipedia) has a completely different justification.  As I said in a comment, it seems odd not to be consistent with `Round`.

Comment: As to  the display digits, there are some cases that confuse me, particularly when it has no digits to display and chooses to display 0.. Others really seem buggy, such as ```96``0``` displaying as 1.*10^2 instead of 1.0*10^2

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you for your findings!
My "problem" is: Either the `Precision`-command is doing "the right thing", or the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NumericalPrecision.html).

It is not that multiplication should in any way change the number of significant digits: If there are two numbers, each with one significant digit, I would expect calculations to be performed like this:

Calculate with any digits and then display the result appropriately (and consistently throughout the system) rounded to the minimum of the significant digits of the original values.

Comment: Michael, I would like to merge this question with [(29122)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29122/121) if possible.  Do you feel that this is reasonable?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree it's a borderline case.  I noticed 29122 earlier, and considered whether this should be marked a duplicate. The most significant difference is the connection with how precision is calculated, which was emphasized in the updates to the question. (It is also why I answered.) I wouldn't object to merging the question. Please see my response to Jinxed to follow this one in a few minutes. I think there is an issue to clear up here that has nothing to do with q/29122. See what you think.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Surely it is not a duplicate.  Rather I hope that the old question could be edited to include both (all) issues, making it a "canonical reference" for rounding-method-issues in *Mathematica*.  I would appreciate your help with the necessary editing *if* you feel this is a reasonable goal.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see.  Well, that's sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @Jinxed Perhaps you are thinking of the approximate [sig-fig rules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) taught in science courses. They are not as precise as numerics routines require. They are easy to compute for short, routine calculations of the sort scientists have to do in their lab work. The results end up being not far off the actual precision. *Mathematica* doesn't do that. It calculates precision correctly, and it displays it correctly. (How would you like a result displayed that has less than one digit of precision?)

Comment: @Jinxed Perhaps you're looking for ```2.5``1 * 2.1``1```?

Comment: @Rojo I can remember being confused by various forms of `0.`, too.  But ```96``0``` has less than two digits of precision, so `1.*10^2` makes sense in one way.  However, I'm confused about the boundary between `1.*10^2` and `96.` (I'm not sure that `1.0*10^2` should be a possibility): try ``96.`1.9822712330395684`` (same as ```96``0```) and ``96.`1.9822712330395726``. I cannot see how the absolute error, precision, or accuracy explains the difference.

Comment: In general, it seems the absolute error should be strictly smaller than the least significant display digit unit, so an accuracy of 0 (or error of 1) demands that the last digit displayed is "tens" (just as if the error was 9, 8 or 4). So the 0 accuracy is the borderline value. Try it with any number that doesn't get a new digit when rounding up, or that doesn't lose all significant digits getting 0 (both weird cases)

Comment: So, ```54``0``` with an error of 1 rounds to tens just like an error of 3.16 (```54``-0.5```). Both give `5.*10^1`. But as you said, misteriously, when you get an extra digit by rounding up, it seems weird (even buggy?): ```96``0``` is `1.*10^2`, ```96``0.001``` is `96.` and ```94``0``` is `9.*10^1`

Comment: Or, for that matter, ```100``0``` which doesn't require rounding up shows as ``1.0*10^2``

Comment: @MichaelE2: `2.5``1` might look like a good idea, as long as you don't `(2.5``1)^5`.

I am sure that calculating precision according to your rules is both straightforward and to that respect correct, however: What the frontend makes of this is quite the opposite: Unintuitive, misleading, and foremost: inconsistent with both `Round` and Wolfram's documentation. "unintuitive" and "misleading" I can handle, inconsistencies, however, are giving me the creeps.

I am a the point of considering to file a report with Wolfram.